# Mount and explore iPhone files in Kubuntu like in Ubuntu Unity [idevicepair]

Tags: kubuntu, iphone

I recently moved to Kubuntu from Ubuntu Unity, but the problem I faced is that when I used Kubuntu, I'm no longer able to explore my iPhone's files like I was able to do in Unity. I'm only able to explore it as a camera from this path:

> camera:/USB%2520PTP%2520Class%2520Camera@usb:002,005/store_00010001/DCIM/

This snapshot from Ubuntu Unity shows what I want to do in Kubuntu:
Ubuntu Unity exploring iPhone files.

[image: iphone]

I installed idevicepair, gvfs, libimobiledevice-utils, ifuse
and successfully paired the device with

```
sudo idevicepair pair
```

and got the following message:

```
SUCCESS: Paired with device 77a871ce98e1b7481c110589dde594d7ada9eeee
```

but there is no pop-up Dolphin window that shows the files of the device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

managed to solve it ..
first install idevicepair

```
sudo apt-get install idevicepair
```

also install ifuse 
(alternative to afc protocols that works - or full compatible with it - on gnome and GVFS )

```
sudo apt-get install ifuse
```

now pair the device and allow access from the device

```
sudo idevicepair pair
```

you will get error msg on the terminal at first and the mobile will show a prompt dialog that requires authentication so allow the device to connect and try pairing again using the following command
 `sudo idevicepair pair`

it should work now.
use this command to verfy handshaking

```
 sudo idevicepair validate
```

now you are almost done but the final step is to mount the device using ifuse

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/foo/ && ifuse /mnt/foo/
```

now you are ready to navigate to the the mounted directory using dolphin but remember to run dolphin as root or you wont be able to see the mounted dir. The problem now that you can not use `chown` or `chmod` to edit ownership so that you can navigate to the dir as normal user

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to get my machine connected to an iphone. I came across this post and found that idevicepair is no longer available.
The mounting process is much simpler now though. All you need is ifuse

I installed ifuse as stated above:

```
sudo apt install ifuse
```

Then the next step is to mount the iphone to a folder. If you use a folder under your own home folder then there will be no need for permissions updates

In my case I did the following to create the folder I want to use as my iphone file system, which is in the root of my home folder:

```
mkdir ~/iphone
```

Then to point the iphone folder to the iphone's file system:

```
ifuse ~/iphone
```

And from this point on you will be able to browse the phone
NB. I found this information from the following youtube link, and thought I would add to this post.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWkIQK-HBDI

I think the kde connect app will become the easier and preferred way to connect your phone to your linux desktop with its gui integration, but once you know how to do it this way you have more than 1 way to connect to your phone's file system.

Hope this helps.