# How do I mount an iPhone on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: mount, iphone

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 22.04.  On the 18.04 machine, I could connect an iPhone 5c via USB, and it would appear in the file explorer as a connected device.  On the 22.04 machine, it does not appear, and I would like it to.

In searching for a solution, I've encountered solutions that recommend certain packages.  None of these packages differ (other than version) between the two machines, so they don't explain the difference in behavior.  In particular, both machines have the `libimobiledevice6` and `gvfs-backends` packages installed.  Neither machine has the `ifuse` package installed.

When I first connected the iPhone to the 22.04 system, the phone asked me to "Trust" the new computer, which I did.

How can I mount an iPhone 5c on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: This open sourece tool did the trick for me. Follow the guide in the following link.
https://opensource.com/article/21/8/libimobiledevice-iphone-linux

Comment: works as here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/749838/mount-and-explore-iphone-files-in-kubuntu-like-in-ubuntu-unity-idevicepair

Answer (score 2):

Try to restart `usbmuxd`:

```
sudo systemctl restart usbmuxd
```

Comment: `usbmuxd` was dead, and I restarted it, so good tip as far as that goes.  This didn't change anything about the problem, though

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try ifuse, but there was a bug with ubuntu 20.04, I guess it it still there with 22.04:
https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse/issues/63

Comment: Can you please [edit] your answer and add the steps required to install `ifuse` and how it can be used to solve the OP's issue? That way your answer will be much more complete and useful. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

It works out of box *the 2nd time* I connected iphone. Somewhat Similar to connecting it to Windows:

1. PC prompts a model dialog for me to "trust" on the phone then retry
2. on the phone, trust
3. on PC, click retry on the dialog.
4. in file explorer, the iphone entry appeared in the left pane.

I'm on 22.04. I've a iphone 12