# Has anyone managed to get data off an original iPhone?

Tags: usb, iphone

I have an *iPhone 1* (3G or whatever it should be called)
I'm on Lubuntu 20.04 running in Virtualbox.

I have tried running iTunes under Windows7 (in Virtualbox), but iTunes doesn't detect a device.
I have tried running iTunes under wine (in Lubuntu 20.04), but iTunes doesn't detect a device.

Various articles (see end*) suggest `libimobiledevice`, `fuse`, `libmuxd`, etc.

I created the mountpoint:
`sudo mkdir /media/iphone`

I get the following:

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:1292 Apple, Inc. iPhone 3G
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ dmesg | grep -i iphone
[  136.336274] usb 1-2: Product: iPhone
[ 1260.165423] usb 1-2: Product: iPhone
```

```
$ sudo idevicepair pair
[sudo] password for alan: 
No device found, is it plugged in?
```

```
$ sudo ifuse /media/iphone
No device found, is it connected?
If it is make sure that your user has permissions to access the raw usb device.
If you're still having issues try unplugging the device and reconnecting it.
```

I have tried unplug/replug.  I have tried rebooting the computer.
Same result.

`ifuse` has an option `-u, --udid UDID       mount specific device by UDID`
However, in the iPhone, `Settings > General > About` only shows `IMEI` and `ICCID`.

Any suggestions much appreciated. Thank you.

*
[How do I mount an iPhone on Ubuntu 22.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1422940/how-do-i-mount-an-iphone-on-ubuntu-22-04)

https://opensource.com/article/21/8/libimobiledevice-iphone-linux

https://www.maketecheasier.com/easily-mount-your-iphone-as-an-external-drive-in-ubuntu/

https://www.bollyinside.com/articles/how-to-use-an-iphone-with-linux/

https://cellularnews.com/mobile-phone/how-to-use-iphone-with-linux-complete-guide/